# How do you make a non-key column unique in SSMS?

Tags: t-sql

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) I have a table with a numeric, surrogate primary key.  I would like to make another column unique, however.  It seems like only primary keys can be made unique, however.

How does one make a non-key column unique, so that the same value may not be entered twice?

---

SQL Server 2012,
SSMS 2012

---

Also, if it matter, I used a numeric surrogate key on the table instead of a natural key because values in the column above, that I need to make unique, may change in the future.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190024(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like only primary keys can be made unique, however.

Try using a unique constraint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx